# How to login as root in vps from main server (Dedicated)

Tags: centos, vps, openvz

how to login as root in VPS from root main server without changing the existing root password?

I have Dedicated server and use virtualizor OpenVZ for make it available for to build vps, but one of my vps i forget the password, and i would like to login as root access in that server via main server.

is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the root password in an OpenVZ container with [`vzctl`](https://openvz.org/Man/vzctl.8):

```
vzctl set CTID --userpassword root:newpassword --save
```

Answer (score 1):

To login as root from the host to an openvz container, without a password:

```
vzctl enter CTID
```